# Uglifying Bootstrap ES6 JS code causes "Modal redeclared" issue

Tags: npm, gruntjs, bootstrap-4, es6-modules, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm getting the error "Modal redeclared" while trying to uglify Bootstrap 4 JS code using Grunt. I found out those are ES6 so I found the [ES6 Uglify for Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/tree/harmony). I'm using the following dependencies

```
"bootstrap": "~4.0.0",
"grunt": "~1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony",
```

Among others. The full error is:

```
>> Uglifying source source/js/site.js failed.
Warning: Uglification failed.
Modal redeclared.
Line 1808 in source/js/site.js
```

That line reads `const Modal = (($) => {`

I'm unsure of how else to get these JS files to compile or uglify with Grunt. Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using the [mangle](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options) option? This should prevent variable names from overlapping.

Comment: I have not tried that. I didn't even see that as an option for the Grunt version of Uglify. I'll try tomorrow

Comment: @Jack I tried the mangle option, with no luck. I tried it in all kinds of ways. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was in the order the files were compiling. I've attached the correct way. Things I noticed:

- Util should be first
- Index goes last
- Popover has to load after tooltip

```js
"build": {
   "src": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/util.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/alert.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/button.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/carousel.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/dropdown.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/modal.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/scrollspy.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/tab.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/popover.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/index.js",
    "source/assets/js/*.js"
    ],
   "dest": "source/js/site.js"
}
```

Yay

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you should be using `browserify` and requiring these files in where necessary. Then you can just uglify your own code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look at those for future builds since I have this already dialed in. Looks like browserify and watchify are nice together